# Problem animating with animatableData in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, animation, rotation, swiftui

SwiftUI not only gives us get automatic animation… it lets us control how the animation occurs, using the `animatableData` property. So cool!

Only I can't get it to work. The following code displays a clock face on the screen (numbers 0…11 ) and shows a toggle switch. Switching the toggle rotates the numbers by 180 degrees, animated. Or that is my intent. But instead of each number taking an animated path around the circle of numbers, each number moves along a straight line to its new position… so that the circle of numbers collapses to the circle's center point and then re-explodes into its new configuration:

[image]

The `animatableData` property is not being referenced by SwiftUI. Any idea why?

(Note that it wouldn't work to use a standard rotation animation, because that would turn all the numbers upside down.)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var state: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CircleView(hoursOffset: CGFloat(state ? 6 : 0 ))
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            Toggle(isOn: $state, label: { Text("Rotate 180°?") })
                .frame(maxWidth: 200).padding()
        }
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    static func onCircle(hours: CGFloat, size: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let radians = (3 - hours) * CGFloat.pi / CGFloat (6)
        let hypotenuse = size / 2
        return CGPoint(x: size / 2 + 0.8 * hypotenuse * cos(radians),
                       y: size / 2 - 0.8 * hypotenuse * sin(radians))
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {

    var hoursOffset: CGFloat

    public var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { hoursOffset }
        set { self.hoursOffset = newValue }
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader() { geo in
            ForEach(0..<12) { hour in
                ZStack {
                    Text("\(hour)")
                        .position(CGPoint.onCircle(hours: CGFloat(hour) + self.hoursOffset, size: geo.size.width))
                        .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2.0))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4. Just `animatableData` in View does not work - you have to put it in `AnimatableModifier`.

[image: demo]

```
struct CircleMoving: AnimatableModifier {
    var hoursOffset: CGFloat
    var hour: CGFloat
    var size: CGFloat

    public var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { hoursOffset }
        set { self.hoursOffset = newValue }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .position(CGPoint.onCircle(hours: hour + hoursOffset, size: size))
    }
}


struct CircleView: View {

    var hoursOffset: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader() { geo in
            ForEach(0..<12) { hour in
                ZStack {
                    Text("\(hour)")
                        .modifier(CircleMoving(hoursOffset: self.hoursOffset, hour: CGFloat(hour), size: geo.size.width))
                }
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 3.0), value: hoursOffset) // !!!
    }
}
```

**Optional:** also I would recommend you round point values for better integrity, however it is not much important.

```
extension CGPoint {
    static func onCircle(hours: CGFloat, size: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let radians = (3 - hours) * CGFloat.pi / CGFloat (6)
        let hypotenuse = size / 2
        return CGPoint(x: (size / 2 + 0.8 * hypotenuse * cos(radians)).rounded(.up),
                       y: (size / 2 - 0.8 * hypotenuse * sin(radians)).rounded(.up))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Asperi — I appreciate it… again!! I'll go play with it. Tell me, if you would: how did you learn about AnimatableModifier and why it will not work, for example, to use `onCircle()` directly as I originally did, rather than inside a modifier? I can't find any documentation for it and I'd love to understand, so if you have any links or tips to share, I'd be very appreciative!

Comment: Any thoughts, @Asperi? See comment above. Thank you!

Comment: @Anton, [here](https://swiftui-lab.com/category/animations/) you can find good materials for start, following just experiment. :)

Comment: Thank you, @Asperi. Actually, that's where I learned a lot about AnimatableData - and why it seemed to me, based on his clock example, that I don't need to use AnimatableModifier (which he does not use for the clock). It was also the only reference I found to AnimatableModifier. Unfortunately I did't find his explanation of AnimatibleModifier very helpful in understanding why you need it here. Though his examples are terrific!

Comment: Hello @Asperi. I notice there's a strange behavior in the code you gave. For some reason the radius of the circle decreases subtly during the animation. You can see it more clearly if you replace the 6 with 60 in `CircleView(hoursOffset: CGFloat(state ? 6 : 0 ))` - the numbers on the outside of the clock converge to a center point while they rotate. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: This is effect of accumulated animations. Fixed by adding `value: hoursOffset` in `CircleView`. See updated.

Comment: @Anton did you perhaps find the answer why only use animatableData doesn't work?

Comment: @sheldor Unfortunately I did not ever figure out why animatableData didn't work; I used AnimatableModifier to make it work. ‍♂️ If you figure it out, please let us know!

Comment: In an other post I saw something what is interesting: If you create a simple Shape View with a path which is an ellipse with position dependent on the angle and you have an angle as animatableData, the shape rotates around when the angle changes with the change of the state. There must be a difference in Shapes

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the evil mathematics...you are calculating the endpositions. Apple does just adding steps from one position to another (as a line) so this is what you see. If you toggle from 0 to 1 it "looks" like a circular move, but it is also linear ;) 
the solution would be, to calculate the x,y positions manually ON the circle depending on your hours offset values

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Chris. But I'm afraid I don't see what you mean. The `CGPoint.onCircle` function that I define does calculate all the intermediate points on the circle, not just the endpoints, and the `animatableData` property I define specifies that all those intermediate values should be used in the animation. Right?

Comment: Or perhaps, @Chris, you could share the code for the screenshot you gave?