# How to give path in SwiftUI an upper and lower bound value (Double) so that one can easily place a view on a custom path

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, path, shapes

I have [this](https://github.com/takasurazeem/FollowPathProblem) repository I built on top of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521118/how-to-move-a-view-shape-along-a-custom-path-with-swiftui#comment107086725_60521118) comment which helped me make an image follow the custom shape path but the problem with this is that it is constantly animating. My idea is to build something like this: `PathFollowView(lowerBound: 0, upperBound: 100, currentValue: 25)`. Now, I am fairly new to SwiftUI and still learning, so I would love to hear from someone who has done extensive shapes that is it possible to give Paths lower and upper bound and then position any SwiftUI view on that path based on a current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your repository and requirement, it seems like the ViewModifier `FollowEffect` does the job, but it's animating from 0 to 1 according to the `flag` state, changing the `pct` value in the ViewModifier.

cancel the animation and the default value of `pct`,
and use the `pct` value to position the indicator on the relevant position using a simple formula:

```
currentValue / upperBound
```