Rotate & animate image along a path in SwiftUI?
I'm trying to create the following animation.
Since last posting, I've managed to orient the image along the path (thanks to swiftui-lab). How do I now flip the image continuously as it follows the path as well as have the path follow the image with animation as can be seen in the linked animation above?
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var animate = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                SemiCircle()
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, dash: [10, 15]))
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                
                Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill").resizable().foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(45))
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50).offset(x: -25, y: -25)
                    .modifier(FollowEffect(pct: animate ? 0 : 1, path: SemiCircle.semiCirclePath(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)), rotate: true))
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 3.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                            animate.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
            .frame(alignment: .topLeading)
        })
        .padding(50)
    }
}

struct SemiCircle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        SemiCircle.semiCirclePath(in: rect)
    }
    
    static func semiCirclePath(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        let radius = min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2
        path.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(180), clockwise: true)
        return path
    }
}

struct FollowEffect: GeometryEffect {
    var pct: CGFloat = 0
    let path: Path
    var rotate = true
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return pct }
        set { pct = newValue }
    }
    
    func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
        if !rotate {
            let pt = percentPoint(pct)
            return ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: pt.x, y: pt.y))
        } else {
            let pt1 = percentPoint(pct)
            let pt2 = percentPoint(pct - 0.01)
            
            let angle = calculateDirection(pt1, pt2)
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: pt1.x, y: pt1.y).rotated(by: angle)
            
            return ProjectionTransform(transform)
        }
    }
    
    func percentPoint(_ percent: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        // percent difference between points
        let diff: CGFloat = 0.001
        let comp: CGFloat = 1 - diff
        
        // handle limits
        let pct = percent > 1 ? 0 : (percent < 0 ? 1 : percent)
        
        let f = pct > comp ? comp : pct
        let t = pct > comp ? 1 : pct + diff
        let tp = path.trimmedPath(from: f, to: t)
        
        return CGPoint(x: tp.boundingRect.midX, y: tp.boundingRect.midY)
    }
    
    func calculateDirection(_ pt1: CGPoint,_ pt2: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let a = pt2.x - pt1.x
        let b = pt2.y - pt1.y
        
        let angle = a < 0 ? atan(Double(b / a)) : atan(Double(b / a)) - Double.pi
        
        return CGFloat(angle)
    }
}


Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521118/how-to-move-a-view-shape-along-a-custom-path-with-swiftui

I did ! I am able to have the image follow the path but haven't figured out the rotation aspect.

Have you considered using SpriteKit ?

I've considered it but the requirement is to do it with SwiftUI due to project constraints.

SwiftUI has a SpriteView ...

Thanks, I'm aware of that but it's not feasible due to factors beyond those that I can explain here. I'm looking for a solution not relying on SpriteKit.

You can apply a Scale transform... calculate the percent between -1.0 and 1.0, apply .scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: pct) ... if pct is -1.0 that effectively "flips the image vertically"

The path in this case is a simple arc, so an Animatable ViewModifier is sufficient for the animation. Some notes:

For the 3D roll, try using rotation3DEffect around the x-axis. This needs to be performed before adding the arc rotation.

I would suggest, the easiest way to implement the rotation effect along the arc is to perform an offset equal to the arc radius, rotate the view, then negate the offset.

If you don't want the arc to be 180 degrees then you can compute the angle and radius using a little trigonometry. I worked this out once for a previous answer, the formula can be borrowed from there.

The path (arc) can be animated using the .trim modifier. However, this modifier only works on a Shape, so a ViewModifier is not able to take the view supplied to it and apply .trim as modifier. What would be great, is if it would be possible to create an animatable ShapeModifier, for animating shapes. Since this is not currently possible, the shape needs to be added to the view by the view modifier, for example, by drawing it in the background.

The animation actually has different phases (take-off, roll, landing, trailing path). A single view modifier can handle all of these phases, but you need to implement the phase logic yourself.

The shadow effect needs to be applied inside the view modifier. If it is applied to the view passed to the view modifier then the shadow rolls too!

The scaling factor and the size of the shadow can depend on the fraction of the "cruise height" that has been reached along the path, to give the impression that the plane is taking off and landing.


The version below uses a single ViewModifier to apply all the animation effects, including the animation of the trailing path (which is added in the background, as explained above). A symbol that looks more like the one in the reference animation would be "location.fill", but I left it as "paperplane.fill", like you were using.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var animate = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let w = proxy.size.width
            let halfWidth = w / 2
            let curveHeight = w * 0.2
            let slopeLen = sqrt((halfWidth * halfWidth) + (curveHeight * curveHeight))
            let arcRadius = (slopeLen * slopeLen) / (2 * curveHeight)
            let arcAngle = 4 * asin((slopeLen / 2) / arcRadius)

            Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(45))
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                .modifier(
                    FlightAnimation(
                        curveHeight: curveHeight,
                        arcRadius: arcRadius,
                        arcAngle: arcAngle,
                        progress: animate ? 1 : 0
                    )
                )
        }
        .padding(30)
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                animate.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FlightPath: Shape {
    let curveHeight: CGFloat
    let arcRadius: CGFloat
    let arcAngle: Double

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + curveHeight))
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY + arcRadius),
            radius: arcRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(-90) - .radians(arcAngle / 2),
            endAngle: .degrees(-90) + .radians(arcAngle / 2),
            clockwise: false
        )
        return path
    }
}

struct FlightAnimation: ViewModifier, Animatable {
    let curveHeight: CGFloat
    let arcRadius: CGFloat
    let arcAngle: Double
    let planeSize: CGFloat = 24
    let flightFractionDoingRoll = 0.4
    let totalRollDegrees: CGFloat = 360
    let maxScaling: CGFloat = 1.8
    let maxShadow: CGFloat = 4
    let trailingFlightPathDurationFraction: CGFloat = 0.3
    var progress: CGFloat

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { progress }
        set { progress = newValue }
    }

    private var totalFlightDuration: CGFloat {
        1 - trailingFlightPathDurationFraction
    }

    private var flightProgress: CGFloat {
        progress / totalFlightDuration
    }

    private var rollBegin: CGFloat {
        ((1 - flightFractionDoingRoll) / 2) * totalFlightDuration
    }

    private var rollEnd: CGFloat {
        totalFlightDuration - rollBegin
    }

    private var rotationAngle: Angle {
        .radians(min(1, flightProgress) * arcAngle) - .radians(arcAngle / 2)
    }

    private var rollAngle: Angle {
        let rollFraction = progress > rollBegin && progress < rollEnd
            ? (progress - rollBegin) / (flightFractionDoingRoll * totalFlightDuration)
            : 0
        return .degrees(totalRollDegrees * rollFraction)
    }

    private var trimFrom: CGFloat {
        progress <= totalFlightDuration
            ? 0
            : (progress - totalFlightDuration) / trailingFlightPathDurationFraction
    }

    private var trimTo: CGFloat {
        progress < totalFlightDuration
            ? progress / totalFlightDuration
            : 1
    }

    private var cruiseHeightFraction: CGFloat {
        let fraction = rollBegin <= 0 || progress >= totalFlightDuration
            ? 0
            : min(progress, totalFlightDuration - progress) / rollBegin
        return min(1, fraction)
    }

    private var scaleFactor: CGFloat {
        1 + (cruiseHeightFraction * (maxScaling - 1))
    }

    private var shadowSize: CGFloat {
        cruiseHeightFraction * maxShadow
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .frame(width: planeSize, height: planeSize)
            .scaleEffect(scaleFactor)
            .rotation3DEffect(
                rollAngle,
                axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0),
                perspective: 0.1
            )
            .offset(y: -arcRadius)
            .rotationEffect(rotationAngle)
            .offset(y: arcRadius)
            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: shadowSize, y: shadowSize)
            .frame(height: curveHeight + (planeSize / 2), alignment: .top)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background {
                FlightPath(curveHeight: curveHeight, arcRadius: arcRadius, arcAngle: arcAngle)
                    .trim(from: trimFrom, to: trimTo)
                    .stroke(.gray, style: .init(lineWidth: 3, dash: [10, 10]))
                    .padding(.top, planeSize / 2)
            }
    }
}


The reference animation also slows in the middle. If you wanted to mimic this too then you could replace the .linear timing curve with a custom timing curve. For example:
withAnimation(
    .timingCurve(0.15, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, duration: 4.5)
    .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
) {
    animate.toggle()
}



EDIT The view modifier works on whatever view it is given. So if you wanted the image to have a white border, as in the reference animation, then a ZStack can be used to layer multiple images to give this effect. For example:
ZStack {
    Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
        .resizable()
        .fontWeight(.black)
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
    Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
        .resizable()
        .fontWeight(.ultraLight)
        .padding(2)
        .foregroundStyle(.red)
}
.scaledToFit()
.rotationEffect(.degrees(45))
.modifier(
    FlightAnimation( /* as before */ )
)



You Sir are a legend! I'm accepting the answer for now even though there's so much for me to unpack here. I may circle back in case I need explanation on parts of the answer, I hope that is okay.

@batman Np, thanks for accepting the answer! The only bit I wasn't able to find a solution for is to give the image a bit of depth (thickness). Don't know how to do that. But in fact, I'm not sure that it would necessarily improve the animation.

@BenzyNeez - slick implementation. If the OP really wants to match the 3D / depth visual effect: close examination of the video shows the arrow has a white border... plus a drop-shadow that slightly animates its offset. Would be interesting to see if your code could be modified to add that.

@DonMag Yes, the view modifier works on whatever view it is given. So this could be a ZStack with layered images that give the effect of a white border. I updated the answer now to include the shadow. This needs to be applied inside the ViewModifier - if it is applied to the view passed to the view modifier then the shadow rolls too! As you mentioned, the reference animation also has a bit of an offset during the roll. This can be achieved by adding a y-offset to the image before applying the 3D rotation. I tried it, but didn't think it looked great, so I left it rolling on its central axis.

@DonMag Couldn't resist updating the answer again to show the white border too!

@BenzyNeez - looks pretty darn close to the original. I don't use SwiftUI, but when I see some of the visual effects (such as .rotation3DEffect) it makes me want to start :)

@BenzyNeez fantastic!
